# Why max heap is changing at runtime?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, java-8, jvm

We have a Java application running in openjdk8 whose max heap memory changes at runtime - what might be the reason of that?

I have found question [Why the heap is changing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468362/why-the-heap-is-changing-in-java) which points to the article which explains difference between `max` and `committed` memory. It seems that in our case these two are usually the same, but not always - see at 11:53 on screenshots below.

Heap can be also changed be young generation serial collector (`-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio`, see [Encourage the JVM to GC rather than grow the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355933/encourage-the-jvm-to-gc-rather-than-grow-the-heap)), however we use parallel collector so this is not the case.

The memory related JVM parameters that we run the application with:

`-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=200M -Xms2000m -Xmx2000m`

Not sure if it's related, the application was doing parallel mark sweep on old generations between 11:55 and 11:58 - at this time there was over 200MB free memory available and we cannot see any reason for that behaviour.

[image: Heap Memory]
[image: Mark Sweep Count]

Comment: The question lacks JVM options and relevant GC logs.

Comment: BTW, `-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is turned on by default.

Comment: @apangin I have added JVM options to the question. Our GC logging is disabled so I can't provide them for this case. We would have to enable them and wait for this to happen again.

Comment: So you are using Parallel GC which has adaptive size policy on by default. Set `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` if you don't want heap generations to resize.

Comment: @apangin how come this is not an answer? Exactly what the OP asked

Answer (score 11):

You are using Parallel GC which has adaptive size policy on by default.
Set `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` if you don't want heap generations to resize.